# regex for repeating characters in a string in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am new to Regex. I have a regex which removes repeating characters from a string.

```
>>> self.repeat_regexp = re.compile(r'(\w*)(\w)\2(\w*)')
>>> self.repl = r'\1\2\3'
```

The above 2 lines of code strips the repeating characters. For example, `loooooooove` goes to `love`.

But I want to change the regex pattern, such that it replaces only if the repeating characters repeat more than 3 times. Expected output:

```
cannot  ---> cannot
loooooooove ----> love
```

I do not understand the regex `r'(\w*)(\w)\2(\w*)'`  and `r'\1\2\3'`
It would be helpful if the above regexs are interpreted in an understandable way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I do not understand the regex --> r'(\w*)(\w)\2(\w*)' and r'\1\2\3' It would be helpful if the above regex's are interpreted in an understandable way.

OK, let’s go:

`(\w*)` is any kind of *word character* (letters, digits, underscore – varies depending on locale settings, can f.e. include french letters with accents), zero or multiple times (by using the *quantifier* `*`).

Next it tries to match just one single word character `(\w)` – and then that same character again, using `\2`, which is a *back reference* to the second match in the expression, which was the `\w` character matched before.

And after that, again zero or multiple word characters, same as at the beginning.

If that expression matches, then `self.repl = r'\1\2\3'` replaces it – again, using back references – with the matches that were made *capturing subpatterns* using parentheses in the search pattern.

So every matched part gets replaced by itself – except for the repeated character match `\2`, which does not have grouping parentheses.

So, if you want to have the repeated char occur at least three times, you modify that part of the expression to `(\w)(\2{2,})'` – `{2,}` is another quantifier saying “match only if the preceding pattern occurs at least two times”. (Only *at least two times*, since the first character is matched by the preceding `(\w)` already.)

I did not get it to work using the leading and trailing `(\w*)` though – but since these also match zero word characters, I think they can be ditched altogether.

So this should do what you want to achieve:

```
self.repeat_regexp = re.compile(r'(\w)(\1{2,})')
self.repl = r'\1'
```

(Since I removed the leading capturing subpattern here, `\2` was replaced by `\1`, referencing the now first capturing subpattern.)

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Now I understand. Thanks :)

Comment: This is still replacing even if there are only 2 repeating characters. My Output: cannot --> canot

Comment: Not in my tests, although I used PHP’s PCRE implementation to test it. I don’t know if there are differences in Python’s implementation of RegExp.