# Regex for a consecutive character occurring at least three times in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have a problem with text preprocessing for tweets.

I would like to replace a character repeated at least three times in a string with the following manner:

```
so        -----> so
loooooove -----> love
sweeeeeet -----> sweet
```

What I did is as follows:

```
text = "this is so soooo sweeeeeeet. I loooove it!"
re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1',text)
```

and

```
re.sub(r'(\w)(\1{3,})',r'\1',text)
```

which is referred from [regex for repeating characters in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544480/regex-for-repeating-characters-in-a-string-in-python)

Both returned the same result as follows:

```
'this is so so swet. I love it!'
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: well e's are replaced by one e. you cant say the structure of a word

Comment: Just replace with `r'\1\1'`. And the pattern is `r'(\w)\1{2,}'` But the problem is you can't know if you need two or one `\1`. You need a spellchecker. Check https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex seems to do exactly what you told it to - it replaced the multiple consecutive characters with a single instance. Regex is not the issue - it's the linguistics.

---

The number of letters in the original word can be ambiguous:

`A) Goooood morning, everyone!`

`B) Goooood, I hate mornings!`

There is no way to know that the original word of `Goooood` in `A)` was `Good` and in `B)` was `God` with pure regex, as it depends on the context in the natural language.

---

One hacky way would be to keep a dictionary of words and just take the longest words that apply when "compressing" the repeated characters (or just use a spellchecker as Wiktor Stribiżew advised), and that would work in the number of cases - but will fail in the example above.

One more sophisticated (but harder to implement) way would be to use some kind of sentence-prediction algorithm to figure out what is the most probable original word in a sentence.

---

In any way, not a trivial problem at all.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I will consider the method you presented above.